# ExpressValidator Is Not A Function

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, express-validator

- I'm building a web login feature using mongodb and node.js. I'm using an express framework
- I've installed express-validator in package.json
- In app.js, lines concerning expressValidator reads:

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value){
    var namespace = param.split('.'),
    root = namespace.shift(),
    formParam = root;
    while(namespace.length){formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';}
    return{param: formParam, msg: msg, value: value};
    }
}));
```

After running 'npm start' on terminal, I get:

```
    > nodeauthorization@0.0.0 start /Users/username/Desktop/nodeauthorization
    > node ./bin/www

    /Users/username/Desktop/nodeauthorization/app.js:44
    app.use(expressValidator({
            ^

    TypeError: expressValidator is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>(/Users/username/Desktop/nodeauthorization/app.js:44:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:945:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Desktop/nodeauthorization/bin/www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:945:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! nodeauthorization@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the nodeauthorization@0.0.0 start script.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you are using this express-validator?

Comment: expres-validator(v6.2.0)? Yes

Comment: In express-validator docs, I didn't see such an usage. Where did you find it?

Comment: https://github.com/VojtaStavik/GetBack2Work-Node/tree/master/node_modules/express-validator under Middleware Options

Comment: This info is very old, seems absolute, please check the current docs:
https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for the [legacy API](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/5.2.0/legacy-api.html) of express validator.

Latest docs can be found [here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/5.2.0/index.html) where the API has changed

This is the official [GitHub](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator) for the package